# Should this code be plain functions or a separate class?

Tags: wordpress, function, oop

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin built on top the OOP structured [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate). I just recently finished some code for setting and displaying 'flash messages', or admin notices as they are called in WP. The result are two functions, one for setting notices (for the current user) and another for displaying notices (for the current user).

```
function ao_set_admin_notice(string $type, string $message) {
    $name = 'ao_admin_notice_user_' . get_current_user_id();
    $value = [
        'type' => $type, 
        'message' => $message,
    ];
    set_transient($name, $value, 45);
}
```

and

```
function ao_admin_notice() {
    $name = 'ao_admin_notice_user_' . get_current_user_id();

    if ($value = get_transient($name)) {
        printf(
            '<div class="notice %s is-dismissible"><p>%s</p></div>', 
            'notice-' . $value['type'], 
            $value['message']
        ); 
        delete_transient($name);
    }
}
```

But I keep asking myself... **Can or should this code be placed in a separate class?**

Given the simplicity of the two functions and can't really see the gain in creating a class with these two (static?) methods (except maybe encapsulation).

The natural usage feels like a simple required file with these two functions inside, on the other hand I'm not used to the OOP way of thinking...

Comment: Unnecessary to do.

Comment: @Dedering: Please, feel free to elaborate =)

Comment: It's rare to see transient functions split into classes. You could ... but why?

Comment: In what way does it matter that this is a transient function? Am asking because I want to understand. Not because I question your statement :)